# Abelian group G is of order $240$, $\sigma(g)=g^{16}\in \text{Aut}(G)$, then #{ker $\sigma$} =?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm told to determine if this is true:

> If $G$ is an abelian group of order $240$. Then the kernel of the map $G\to G$ given by $\sigma(g)=g^{16}$ has 16 elements.

Since the group is not determined  and there are $5$ abelian groups of order $240$ up to isomorphism. They are $\mathbb{Z}_2\bigotimes\mathbb{Z}_2\bigotimes\mathbb{Z}_2\bigotimes\mathbb{Z}_2\bigotimes\mathbb{Z}_3\bigotimes\mathbb{Z}_5$ ,
$\mathbb{Z}_4\bigotimes\mathbb{Z}_2\bigotimes\mathbb{Z}_2\bigotimes\mathbb{Z}_3\bigotimes\mathbb{Z}_5$,
$\mathbb{Z}_8\bigotimes\mathbb{Z}_2\bigotimes\mathbb{Z}_3\bigotimes\mathbb{Z}_5$,
$\mathbb{Z}_{16}\bigotimes\mathbb{Z}_3\bigotimes\mathbb{Z}_5$,
$\mathbb{Z}_4\bigotimes\mathbb{Z}_4\bigotimes\mathbb{Z}_3\bigotimes\mathbb{Z}_5$.
I'm not sure if I need to discuss each case.

Comment: Hint: Start by writing $G$ as a direct sum of a $2$-group and the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Following your approach, you can combine all cases to write
$$
G=H\times \mathbb{Z}/15,
$$
where $H$ is an abelian group of order $16$.  An arbitrary element of $G$ can be written as
$$
g=h+k.
$$
Then, since $G$ is abelian,
$$
\sigma(g)=\sigma(h)+\sigma(k).
$$
Use Lagrange's theorem to study $\sigma(h)$ and Fermat's little theorem or Lagrange's theorem to study $\sigma(k)$.

Comment: $G=H\times \mathbb{Z}_{15}$, for$g\in G$ ,$g=h\cdot k,\sigma(g)=(hk)^{16}=h^{16}k^{16}=\sigma(g)\cdot \sigma(k)$, $h \in H$ and $H$ is of order 16 hence $\sigma(h)=e$ while $k \in \mathbb{Z}_{15}$ hence $\sigma(k)=k^{16}=k$. Therefore $\sigma(g)=\sigma(k)=k $. $Ker=\{g=(h,e_k),h\in H, e_k \in Z_{15}$ is the identity in$ Z_{15}\}$ Hence $|Ker(\sigma)|=16$. Right?

Comment: Yes, that's how to finish it.